# % based triangle that keeps the height of neighbouring div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, responsive

```css
section {
  height: 100%;
}
.work-left {
  width: 35vw;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  background-color: #3B5D2A;
  position: relative;
}
.work-right {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.work-left-triangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #81B268;
  position: absolute;
}
.work-right-title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #AEDF95;
}
.image-container {
  width 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <div class="work-left">
    <div class="work-left-triangle"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="work-right">
    <div class="work-right-title"></div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/Singapore_Botanic_Gardens_Cactus_Garden_2.jpg">
      <img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/Singapore_Botanic_Gardens_Cactus_Garden_2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

I am trying to make a responsive triangle as part of the header, that keeps it proportions when resizing with the neighbouring div. Code pen link with my structure here. I am having trouble to make a triangle that sits in the right space (tried rotating and overflog hidden) and on top of that resizes with the div next to it.

To view directly in Codepen click [here](http://codepen.io/chrisvall/pen/qZoqeJ)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a grafient here :   `background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #81B268 50%, #3B5D2A 50%);`

Run snippet below to find out or [see the fork of your pen](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/oxqZNj)

```css
section {
  height: 100%;
  /* demo snippet purpose */ min-width:670px;
}
.work-left {
  width: 35vw;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  background-color: #3B5D2A;
  position: relative;
}
.work-right {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.work-left-triangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #81B268;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #81B268 50%, #3B5D2A 50%);
  position: absolute;
}
.work-right-title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #AEDF95;
}
.image-container {
  width 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="work-left">
    <div class="work-left-triangle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="work-right">
    <div class="work-right-title"></div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/Singapore_Botanic_Gardens_Cactus_Garden_2.jpg">
      <img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/Singapore_Botanic_Gardens_Cactus_Garden_2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks so much, so much simpler than all the things I tried!

Answer (score 0):

Insert an image inside the desired div element and the image should contain your desired triangle and leave the bottom-left transparent. Then set the background of the div enclosing the image to the darker green.